# Python - clicking on button with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriver

This is the button I'm trying to click:

```
<button class="stkv-c-button stkv-us-button-color--background 
    stkv-u-background-color-transition-150 
    stkv-us-button-color--border stkv-us-button-color 
    stkv-us-button-color--fill stkv-c-button 
    stkv-c-button--raised stkv-c-button--big">

    <span class="stkv-c-button__label stkv-c-button__label--big">Vote Now</span>
</button>
```

This is the xpath (pulled from Firefox):

```
[@id='root']/html/body/div/div/div[3]/div/div/footer/div/button"
```

I've tried a wide variety of ways to click on the button, all to no avail.

```
self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='root']/html/body/div/div/div[3]/div/div/footer/div/button").click()
self.driver.findElement(By.id("Vote Now")).click()
self.driver.find_element_by_name("Vote").send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
self.driver.find_element_by_id('stkv-c-button stkv-us-button-color--background stkv-u-background-color-transition-150 stkv-us-button-color--border stkv-us-button-color stkv-us-button-color--fill stkv-c-button stkv-c-button--raised stkv-c-button--big').click()
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

I'm not having any luck with it.

Comment: What happens when you try to use that code?  Does it throw an ElementNotFound exception?

Answer (score 1):

You can find the button by display text on it.

```
locator = "//button[span[text()='Vote Now']]"
self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(locator).click()
```

Answer (score 1):

Your button doesn't have an id or name, so the `find_element_by_name` and `find_element_by_id` methods will not work.  `find_element_by_class_name` seems like the logical choice, but unfortunately it only expects only 1 class, and since your button has multiple classes, it won't work either.  I would try locating the button with its CSS selector:

```
self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector('button.stkv-c-button.stkv-us-button-color--background.stkv-u-background-color-transition-150.stkv-us-button-color--border.stkv-us-button-color.stkv-us-button-color--fill.stkv-c-button.stkv-c-button--raised.stkv-c-button--big').click()
```

As long as there isn't another button on the page with the exact same CSS selector, this should give you the correct button.  In general, if you want to find an element that has multiple classes, e.g. `<button class="A B C">MyButton</button>`, then you could do it with:

```
self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector('button.A.B.C')
```

Answer (score 1):

**Use this XPath :** `//button[normalize-space()='Vote Now']`

Answer (score 1):

As per the HTML you have shared to `click()` on the button with text as **Vote Now** you can use either of the following solution:

- `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("span.stkv-c-button__label.stkv-c-button__label--big").click()
  ```
- `XPATH`:

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_css_selector("//span[@class='stkv-c-button__label stkv-c-button__label--big' and contains(.,'Vote Now')]").click()
  ```